# Relation between Lie algebra being simple and its representation being irreducible

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Is there any relation between Lie algebra being simple and its representation being irreducible?

---- sorry for being vague; here's some detail about this question:

-- If $g$ is simple, then $g$ can certainly have decomposable representations, for instance, just take two representations on $V_1$ and $V_2$, and we have a decomposable representation on $V_1\oplus V_2$.

-- On the other hand, if $g$ is not simple, say $g = g_1 \oplus g_2$, but $g$ has an irreducible representation on $V$, then, is it true that either $g_1$ acts on $V$ trivially or $g_2$ acts on $V$ trivially?

Comment: What do you mean with “its representation”? In general, a Lie algebra has infinitely many representations. And it is not true that every non-simple Lie algebra is the direct sum of two Lie algebras.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_theorem_on_complete_reducibility

Comment: No, there is no relation. Non-simple Lie algebras do have irreducible representations and simple Lie algebras do have non-irreducible representations.

Comment: Is there an easy example, that for a Lie algebra g which equals g1 direct sum g2, the g can have an irreducible representation?

Comment: @Hao: Take any irreducible representation of $g_1$ and precompose it with the projection $g\rightarrow g_1$.

Comment: @Hao: Take an abelian Lie algebra and a one dimensional trivial representation.

Comment: You could check the irreducibility of the adjoint representation for  a relation with simplicity